# mysql - how to join with dynamin column in table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, polymorphic-associations

I have three tables like the following:

calls_list (table)

| id | line | rel_type | rel_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | user | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | lead | 1 |

users (table)

| id | name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mehran | 99999 |
| 2 | reza | 222222 |

leads (table)

| id | title | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lead_1 | confirmed |
| 2 | lead_2 | pending |

I want to say on the calls_list table when select If the rel_type column is equal to the lead value, join the lead table
But if the rel_type column is equal to the user value, join the users table

my query is :

SELECT * FROM calls_list as calls
LEFT OUTER JOIN users as users ON users.id = calls.rel_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead as lead ON lead.id = calls.rel_id

but not working

Is this possible? Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict each join to only those of the right type:

```
SELECT * 
FROM calls_list AS c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS u 
  ON u.id = c.rel_id AND c.rel_type = 'user'
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead AS l 
  ON l.id = c.rel_id AND c.rel_type = 'lead'
```